# calcular la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con la clase datepicker

Tags: php, datepicker

Quisiera calcular la edad de un usuario a partir de su fecha de nacimiento, de manera que cuando se ingrese la fecha de nacimiento en el:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" class="datepicker" />
```

y que automáticamente se cargue en el

```
<input type="text" name="edad"  id="edad" value="<?php echo $edad;?>" readonly="true"/>
```

Pero no lo consigo, actualmente tengo esto:

```
<?
function edad($fecha_nacimiento) { 
    $tiempo = strtotime($fecha); 
    $ahora = time(); 
    $edad = ($ahora-$tiempo)/(60*60*24*365.25); 
    $edad = floor($edad); 
    return $edad; 
} 
?>
```

El formato del datepicker es `format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' // foramto de fecha`

Comment: Aquí te dejo un link que explica como calcular la edad con php (https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_PHP/Ejemplos/Calcular_edad) espero que te sirva

Answer (score 9):

Yo creo que una de las maneras más fáciles de calcular la edad es obteniendo la diferencia en años directamente desde la fecha actual hasta la fecha del cumpleaños con la función `diff`.

Sin embargo, para que el `DateTime` funcione correctamente tendrás que indicar los meses en primer lugar y después el día. Es decir si hubieras nacido el día 25/09/1954 tendría que ser 09/25/1954.

Por otro lado, tal y como ha apuntado `@jotaelesalinas`, un formato mucho más intuitivo y que puedes utilizar en casi todos los `DateTime` (digo casi todos por si hay alguno que no lo haga, la verdad que lo desconozco) es el formato `YYYY-MM-DD`. De esta manera es mucho más fácil detectar el día y el mes de una manera mucho más rápida sin confusiones.

```
<?php
    $cumpleanos = new DateTime("1982-06-03");
    $hoy = new DateTime();
    $annos = $hoy->diff($cumpleanos);
    echo $annos->y;
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e43f7214922b5858b753a58225efccdedbb73dd6)**.

Comment: gracias amigo ejecute tu código con mi fecha de nacimiento y dice que tengo 35 y no lo es exactamente porque tengo 34 en junio cumplo 35

Comment: @yoclens ¿Cómo pusiste la fecha?

Comment: 03/06/1982 igual al formato que pusiste

Comment: @yoclens Recuerda que los meses van como en el formato inglés. Es decir, primero van los meses y después los días. Edito mi respuesta ya que me olvidé mencionarlo.

Comment: así falte 1 día para el cumpleaños debe calcular la edad correcta que en mi caso seria 34

Comment: @yoclens Compruébalo cambiando de lugar los meses y los días. He comprobado tu fecha y también salen 34.

Comment: Utiliza siempre fechas en formato `YYYY-MM-DD` ([estándar ISO 8601](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). Todas las clases DateTime que conozco las reconocen perfectamente y te ahorrarás muchos quebraderos de cabeza.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas Yo en realidad he visto ambas formas en multitud de sitios aunque si que es verdad que la tuya es mucho más intuitiva. ¡Gracias por el apunte! Ahora mismo edito la respuesta para añadir la info.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero con el formato de fecha `YYYY-MM-DD` la da bien la edad

Comment: para mi caso debería quedar asi: `<?php
    $fecha_nacimiento = new DateTime("yyyy-mm-dd");
    $hoy = new DateTime();
    $annos = $hoy->diff($fecha_nacimiento);
    echo $annos->y;
?>` porque y a calcular la edad con el datepicker

Comment: @yoclens Sí, yo puse una fecha para que se viera realmente como funcionaba. Por supuesto tendrás que sustituir la fecha por la que recuperes del DatePicker

Comment: Es lo malo de los formatos de fechas americano y europeo. Nunca sabes cómo está configurado el ordenador. O los ordenadores (dev, staging, production, etc). Por eso YYYY-MM-DD nunca falla.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te puede ayudar, tengo esta función que te devuelve la edad

```
function busca_edad($fecha_nacimiento){
$dia=date("d");
$mes=date("m");
$ano=date("Y");


$dianaz=date("d",strtotime($fecha_nacimiento));
$mesnaz=date("m",strtotime($fecha_nacimiento));
$anonaz=date("Y",strtotime($fecha_nacimiento));


//si el mes es el mismo pero el día inferior aun no ha cumplido años, le quitaremos un año al actual

if (($mesnaz == $mes) && ($dianaz > $dia)) {
$ano=($ano-1); }

//si el mes es superior al actual tampoco habrá cumplido años, por eso le quitamos un año al actual

if ($mesnaz > $mes) {
$ano=($ano-1);}

 //ya no habría mas condiciones, ahora simplemente restamos los años y mostramos el resultado como su edad

$edad=($ano-$anonaz);


return $edad;


}
```